# NFS mounted from Mac OS X Lion doesn't update

Tags: linux, mac-osx, nfs

Using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3, I mount my NFS share exported from a Linux machine like this:
My machine is a Linux 3.2.0-17-generic.

```
$ sudo mount_nfs -P precise:/media/sda2/datas/SAB /media/nfs1
```

However, after changes have been done on the exported directories on the Linux side, they are not always visible in the Finder. New directories are not visible, or files keep their previous name.
Am I using `mount_nfs` incorrectly ?